# i added library into project, but idea doesn't see the class

Tags: java, class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INksv.jpg)I'm adding an open source library to a project, but my library isn't listed in Externak Libraries I'm missing the "compile".[I can see the path and "class.java" but I can't use it in the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6Bm0.jpg)

Comment: how are you adding it? by looking at that print-screen, I would reckon incorrectly. Do you use a DM? (Dependency Management tool)

Comment: I added modules in idea/ Use Project Setting-> Modules

Comment: [Have you read this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html)?

Comment: a 'module' and an external library are not the same.

Comment: i added sources code, but i should added class.jar  i don't know how do it